# Stored Procedure - count of distinct column value in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which has 2 parameters: `@datestart` and `@dateend`. This stored procedure has one `select` statement with a `Count` of column values of each and group by.

This is my table with values

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReqInfo]
(
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [NameOfModel] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
```

| CreatedDate | NameOfModel |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-09 13:15:45.9741171 | VM |
| 2023-03-09 13:27:08.8638566 | SA |
| 2023-03-09 13:37:23.8584554 | VM |
| 2023-03-13 10:16:41.8433846 | SA |
| 2023-03-27 20:16:00.4249625 | IP |
| 2023-04-03 10:35:16.0140792 | IP |
| 2023-04-04 12:37:40.3464878 | CO |
| 2023-04-04 15:09:36.7676324 | IP |
| 2023-04-05 07:16:35.1959935 | VM |
| 2023-04-12 08:24:04.0562298 | CO |
| 2023-05-11 09:48:38.5094338 | CO |

This is select statement

```
SELECT  
    NameOfModule AS ModuleName, 
    COUNT(*) NumberOfRecords
FROM
    ReqInfo
GROUP BY  
    NameOfModule;
```

It computes the count of each model in the `NameOfModule` column:

| ModuleName | NumberOfRecords |
| --- | --- |
| CO | 3 |
| IP | 3 |
| SA | 2 |
| VM | 3 |

I want to use this `Select` statement in the dynamic stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pie_percentage
    @datestart datetime2 = NULL,
    @dateend datetime2 = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    SET @sql = '
    // Select statement to count each module present in NameOFModule
    WHERE 1=1';

    IF @datestart IS NOT NULL
        SET @sql += ' AND CreatedDate >= @_date_start';

    IF @dateend IS NOT NULL
         SET @sql += ' AND CreatedDate < @_date_end';

    PRINT @sql;  

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
N'
@_date_start datetime2,
@_date_end datetime2', 
@_date_start = @datestart,
@_date_end = @dateend;
```

I don't know how to use 'group by' inside the dynamic T-SQL stored procedure - how do I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Store your group by in a separate variable, and concatenate it to your sql variable after you build the where clause?  Not positive I understand your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need New variable for group by

```
alter PROC pie_proc --'2023-03-13 10:16:41.8433846','2023-04-05 07:16:35.1959935'
@start_date datetime2 = NULL,
@end_date datetime2 = NULL
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = '
SELECT  NameOfModule as ModuleName, COUNT(*) NumberOfRecords FROM RequestInfo 
Where  1=1  ';
DECLARE @sqlGROUPBY nvarchar(max)=' GROUP BY  NameOfModule ;'


IF @start_date IS NOT NULL
SET @sql += '
AND CreatedDate >= @_date_start';

IF @end_date IS NOT NULL
SET @sql += '
AND CreatedDate < @_date_end';


set @sql=@sql+@sqlGROUPBY
PRINT @sql;  
EXEC sp_executesql @sql ,
N'
@_date_start datetime2,
@_date_end datetime2', 
@_date_start = @start_date,
@_date_end = @end_date;
end
```

Example

```
EXEC pie_proc @start_date = null, @end_date = '2023-05-10 00:00:00'
```

Result:

| ModuleName | NumberOfRecords |
| --- | --- |
| CO | 2 |
| IP | 3 |
| SA | 2 |
| VM | 3 |

Comment: `EXEC pie_proc @start_date = null, @end_date = '2023-05-10 00:00:00' `                               If i execute this I'm getting error like this ```SELECT  NameOfModule as ModuleName, COUNT(*) NumberOfRecords
FROM RequestInfo
Where1=1
  AND DateCreated < @_end_date
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near '='.```

Comment: you can change tablename and field in line "SET @sql = '
SELECT  NameOfModel as ModuleName, COUNT(*) NumberOfRecords
FROM ReqInfo
Where 1=1'; , I use tabke in post ,secend you must add space this line "where  1=1 "
"

Comment: I have changed that one still it shows me this error ``` SELECT  NameOfModule as ModuleName, COUNT(*) NumberOfRecords FROM ReqInfo Where1=1   AND DateCreated < @_end_date Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38 Incorrect syntax near '='```

Comment: I edited my code Based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the group by at the end of your @sql

```
set @sql += '
group by NameOfModule';
```

But may I recommend a way to avoid the dynamic sql?

```
SELECT  NameOfModule as ModuleName, COUNT(*) NumberOfRecords
FROM ReqInfo
WHERE CreateDate between coalesce(@_date_start,CreatedDate) and coalesce(@_date_end,CreateDate)
GROUP BY NameOfModule;
```

Comment: I have a few condition to satisfy. So for that, I need dynamic SQL. Thanks